# error: 'noexcept' does not name a type

Tags: c++, noexcept

Seems like it never happened to anyone so I guess I'm doing something wrong...
The error I get is:

```
error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
error: 'noexcept' does not name a type
```

the code is this:

```
void* operator new (size_t size) noexcept
    {return foo(size);}
```

also the code is in macro actually, if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: is the C++11 mode enabled?

Comment: Have you defined -std=... ?

Comment: Show your compiler command line, please.

Comment: It's a big project so I'm not sure I'm looking at the right makefiles. I will check that out and let you know if it was that. Thank you

Comment: Seems you are forced to use older C++ standard. Try `throw()` instead of `noexcept`.

Comment: I got this compiling an older version of qt-creator with a newer version of Qt5.